# getting the smallest value php

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve the smallest value from an array. Here is my code:

```
$postID = get_the_id();
$variationP = get_post_meta($postID, '_variations', TRUE);
print_r($variationP);
```

This outputs the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

I am then looping through the array like this:

```
foreach ($variationP as $price){
    echo $price;
}
```

Which then outputs the results like this:

```
123
```

How do I go about returning only the smallest result? I need just `1` to be returned.

Comment: Have you ever tried to search the manual [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) ?

Comment: yes i have been experimenting with min, but cannot get it to work. Could you post up an example please?

Comment: @danyo: Why then did you not say that you have tried `min` and shown us the attempt, along with a description of how it did not work for you?

Comment: `echo min($variationP);`

Comment: `echo min(get_post_meta($postID, '_variations', TRUE));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just echo array: [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) returns the numerically lowest of the parameter values or array.

```
echo min($variationP);
```

Comment: Thanks Bora, this did the trick!

Comment: @danyo you can find all funtions on [php.net](http://www.php.net/) easily ;)

Comment: The description is not fully correct. min returns the parameter which - when casted to integer - is the lowest integer value - but the original value is returned. Take especially care with strings (as in the question). Also this has been already answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you want algorithm (not using **min**), it's really easy:

```
$min = 0;

function minPrice($elements){

    foreach ($elements as $price){
        if($min > $price){
            $min = $price;
        }
    }
    return $min;
}
```

It's good solution when you compare more complex elements, for example models from orm.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `min()` function:

```
$array = Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 );

$minimum = min($array); 

echo $minimum; // 1
```

Comment: Not sure why you did answer while it was already clear in the comments **and** @Bora's answer ...

Comment: @HamZa Bora's answer wasn't visible to me when I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) function to get the smallest number in an array.

```
$a = array(3, 1, 2);
echo min($a);
```

This code output:

```
1
```

Comment: Please don't repeat something that's already answered

Answer (score 0):

use `min()` function to get minimum value.